# Cassandra: Using LongType

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying to insert data into a ColumnFamily with "CompareWith" attribute "LongType". However, when trying to insert data under numerical keys, I get a thrift error.

When attempting the same operation with the cassandra-cli program, I get the error "A long is exactly 8 bytes". How can I resolve this? Should I use a different comparison type?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the cli can't insert binary data.

there are examples in test/system/test_server.py of inserting Long data in python.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I need to use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php to pack the key into an 8-byte binary string

Answer (score 0):

The cassandra-cli program supports *functions* for the **set** command. (details from "help set;" in the cli)

With the following schema:

```
create column family Data 
 with key_validation_class = LongType
 and comparator = LongType
 and default_validation_class = LongType;
```

I can do the following in the cli

```
set Data[long(2)][long(22)]=long(1022);
```